A flexible Serialisation/deserialisation "protocol" that can omit property name?
I would like to shrink my json response for large API call.
I know there is MessagePack that can be used for that. But there is some downside which I would prefer not dealing with.
In most of my usecases, half(+) of the data is the key name that are repeated for each property.
So I was wondering if there was a serialisation/deserialisation "protocol" that can omit propertyname and if its able to zip the data its event better! Ideally in c#.
Maybe by giving a context/schema on the answer itself, so it can be more easly/flexible parsable on the client?
I've got a dummy example, which is an api call that return 100 000 cars and ~425 000 wheels and its inspired by OpenAPI spec. Check "data" property in json below.
//C# Class
public class Car
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public List<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}

public class Wheel
{
    public double Diameter { get; set;}
    public string TireSize { get; set; }
    public string BoltPattern { get; set; }
}

//here is the fictive/wanted response that i would like to received and parse ... I've inspire the json response based on OpenAPI spec, but... could be anything!
{
    "responseDataType": {//Property always there to tell that type is under the "data" property
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "$ref": "#/schemas/Car"
        }
    },
    "schemas": {//Template/type of the "data" property
        "Car": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "year": {
                    "type": "integer",
                },
                "model": {
                    "type": "string",
                },
                "wheels": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/schemas/Wheel"
                    },
                }
            },
        },
        "Wheel": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "diameter": {
                    "type": "number",
                },
                "tireSize": {
                    "type": "string",
                },
                "boltPattern": {
                    "type": "string",
                }
            },
        }
    }
    "data":[
         {99 998 more rows...},
         //As you can see the key are not repeated. 
         //But Deserializer would be parsing according to the provided "schemas"/"responseDataType". 
         //Could also be not indented to save more KB, zipped?
        {
            2000,
            "Toyota",
            [
                {16,"275/40r16","4x100"},
                {16,"275/40r16","4x100"},
                {16,"275/40r16","4x100"},
                {16,"275/40r16","4x100"}            
            ]
        },
        {
            2005,
            "Jeep",
            [
                {17,"33x12.5","5x127"},
                {17,"33x12.5","5x127"},
                {17,"33x12.5","5x127"},
                {17,"33x12.5","5x127"}, 
                {17,"33x12.5","5x127"}          
            ]
        },
        {...99 998 more rows}
    ]
}


Have you "zipped" the data and compared the size (versus unzipped). You're, in effect, trying to build a better "zipper"; since zip should account for "duplicate strings" to start with.

Just use GRPC:

fully supported in .NET
fast
binary serialization
automatic source generation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-9.0
For your case schema is absolutely simple :-D
message Wheel{
    double diameter = 1;
    string tireSize = 2;
    string boltPattern = 3;
}

message Car{
    int32 year = 1;
    string name = 2;
    repeated Wheel wheels = 3;
}


Protobuf. Optionally with gRPC (which uses protobuf by default). And in pure C# terms: protobuf-net (and protobuf-net.Grpc) allow everything to be done in your model:
[ProtoContract]
public class Car
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public List<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}

Etc

Will check proto! Thanks

Since my goal was to reduce the json overall size by not impacting perfomance/code too much, the best thing I found is that you can register GZIP/ BR to your c# api like so.
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.EnableForHttps = true;
    options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
});
builder.Services.Configure<BrotliCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest;
});

builder.Services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest;
});
builder.Services.AddRequestDecompression();


//[...]
//var app = builder.Build();
app.UseResponseCompression();
app.UseRequestDecompression();

Then call the api with gzip(or br) under Accept-Encoding header like so: Accept-Encoding:gzip
Depending on the client it migth just work out of the box. And for my specific usecase I went from ~58mb to ~9.4mb.
Depending on your usecase gRPC can be more appropriate.
